# How can I specify a release branch regular expression in Jenkins job configuration

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In the Branches to build field in Jenkins I would like it to use a branch name with the prefix:

```
Production-release-
```

A number would follow the second dash as supplied by our groovy script.
What is the proper syntax to show a wildcard at the end of this prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use it in a `branch` statement in declarative syntax, you can use an asterisk (*). `Production-release-*` should do the job.